# GCM push message with high frequency

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am planning to implement Android push notification serivce for an app that might require receiveing even two messages per device per second. I would like to know if GCM Push messaging is the way to go or should I stick to SyncAdapter or some other technology? Single device will receive up to few thousand notifications per day. Message size will be very small to 4kb limit is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is critical that all of the messages reach the device and none are lost, GCM alone is not the right choice, since in case GCM server would temporarily lose connection with a device, there's a limit to the number of messages that would be stored for later delivery for that device in the GCM server.

Therefore, if you have to update your app that frequently, you should probably keep an open connection between your server and your app, and load data from the server periodically.

Answer (score 0):

Though the GCM server limits the number of messages that will be stored for later delivery in the case of a device disconnect, you can always create a collapse_key.

According to GCM documentation, if there is already a message with the same collapse key (and registration ID) stored and waiting for delivery, the old message will be discarded and the new message will take its place (that is, the old message will be collapsed by the new one).

Essentially, if you only need the most recent push notifications rather than all prior sent, GCM is acceptable for sending push notifications with high frequency.

You can read more about this in the [GCM Advanced Topics](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html).

Comment: I am creating similar app. GCM is not reliable for fast messaging, the connection breaks often.